Finding a Polynomial Equation in $x$ and $y$. Given $x=a+b$ and $y=ab$.
I am working with the relationships $x=a+b$ and $y=ab$, where $a,b,x$ and $y$ are real variables. I would like to know if it is possible to derive any polynomial equation $p(x,y)=0$ that relates $x$ and $y$.
To clarify, I am looking for a polynomial $p(x,y)$ in terms of $x$ and $y$ that is independent on $a$ and $b$ such that $p(x,y)=0$.
I tried to find the relationship using the equlity $(a + b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2$, which gives $x^2 = a^2 + b^2 + 2y$. However, this still involves the variables $a$ and $b$.
I also constructed the equation $t^2 - (a + b)t + ab = 0$, which can be rewritten as $t^2 - xt + y = 0$, where the solutions are $t = a$ and $t = b$. But I’m still unsure how to proceed from here.
Any insights or references would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

$x^2-4y=(a-b)^2$

Alternatively, assuming that $~a \neq 0,~$ $$x = a + \frac{y}{a} \implies ax = a^2 + y.$$

But this equation contains a and b.

Well technically $x^2-(x^2-4y)=4y$ is a valid equation

Why do you expect an equation to (presumably) restrict $x, y$? As mentioned above, any reals that satisfy $x^2\geqslant 4y$ give you real $(a, b)$ satisfying the given conditions.

Since you've mentioned that $x,y,a,b$ are real variables, I guess there's no way to obtain a polynomial equation entirely in terms of $x$ and $y$ $($this rules out the equation $x^2-4y=(a-b)^2)$
The only relation I can think of is this $$\boxed{x^2-4y\ge0}$$

I need equation. But this is an inequality.
